# How to get a list of index values after groupby().mean() in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, mean

I am stuck with this. I would like to get a list of `name` from the following, a result of `groupby().mean()` with the application of pandas DataFrame. Most specifically, I would like to get `["John", "Mary", "Suzan", "Eric"]`.

```
      score
name       
John   85.0
Mary   86.5
Suzan  90.0
Eric   100.0
```

The result of the above is `means`, which comes from the following:

```
data = pandas.DataFrame({"name": names, "score": scores})
means = data.groupby("name").mean()
```

As now I have `means`, I would like to get a list of names from `'means' - ["John", "Mary", "Suzan", "Eric"]`. Is this achievable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just look at the index if you have an Index. If you have a MultiIndex, see @jezrael's answer with `get_level_values`.

```
means.index.tolist()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
print (list(means.index))
['John', 'Mary', 'Suzan', 'Eric']
```

Another better solution is use [`Series.unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unique.html) and omit `groupby`:

```
print (data.name.unique())
['John' 'Mary' 'Suzan' 'Eric']
```

Comment: Thank you. This is also elegant.

Comment: It is great, but my task is to pickle means and load it in another file for further manipulation. unique() is absolutely better if I am not assigned to do the pickling task :) Thank you very much for your help :)